How do I include a JavaScript Lambda layer into a TypeScript Serverless Framework project?
I'm working with an AWS Lambda Layer called "helpers". It is written in JavaScript as an ES module. I'm trying to set up a new TypeScript project using Serverless Framework. I want to import the layer that's on the account. This is my serverless file.
service: stub
frameworkVersion: "3"

custom:
  aws:
    layers:
      helpers:
        version: 1
  basePath: /stub
  esbuild:
    external:
      - helpers

 plugins:
  - serverless-esbuild

// ...

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
          path: ${self:custom.basePath}
          method: get
    layers:
      - {layer_arn_from_custom}


my handler is:
import { createLogger } from 'helpers';

export const hello = (event) => {
  const logger = createLogger();
  // ...
}

Serverles-esbuild cannot tell "helpers" is a Lambda layer and cannot resolve it properly. Even though the layer is associated with the Function (confirmed in the AWS console), executing the Function results in an import error. Adding a .d.ts file for "helpers" did not fix the problem.
